# Disable click event in gridview android

Tags: android

**how to disable and enable gridview click event in android programmatically in android**

i have tried this, But it is not working

```
grid.setClickable(false);
grid.setFocusable(false);
grid.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Answer (score 7):

try this..

```
grid.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have `setEnabled(false)` to disable click on item. This can be even done in the `adapter` by overriding two methods

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
   // Return true for clickable, false for not
   return false;
}
```